# Siri suggestion still showing after turned off

Tags: spotlight, siri, ios

I had install iOS10 and i don't like siri suggested app, so i had turn it off according to [this](https://www.igeeksblog.com/turn-off-siri-suggestions-in-spotlight-search-in-ios-9/), but it didn't work. It still shows on notification center. 
I tried restarting it as well but nothing. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 2):

On the Notification screen, scroll to the bottom and tap `Edit`.

On the list of apps, tap the red circle next to `Siri App Suggestions`, then tap `Remove`.

On the top right of the screen, tap `Done`.

This should remove Siri App Suggestions from Notification screen immediately, no need to reboot.