# How to completely disable, not just hide, Siri Suggestions in iOS?

Tags: ios, search, siri

I'm trying to turn off Siri Suggestions in iOS, with the goal of not having my device build patterns of what I do (regardless of whether it sends them, which it probably doesn't).

I've turned off all three switches under Siri Suggestions in Siri and Search settings. Does that turn off this feature completely, or do I still have to go through every app and turn it off for each one individually?

---

*Update:* Even with those switches off, in Siri and Search settings it also lists things I've recently done under Suggested Shortcuts. This seems to be part of the same feature. Both of the apps listed had "Search, Suggestions, and Shortcuts" turned on below, but it looks like it still saves data *even when this switch is off for the app.* I tried sending a message to myself with it off and again with it on, and both showed up under All Shortcuts.

**How do I disable this feature so that it doesn't gather data on me?** (Whether it's sending it anywhere isn't my concern, I know it probably doesn't. I just find it a little creepy that my phone is recording everything I do on it.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Siri suggestion still showing after turned off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252925/siri-suggestion-still-showing-after-turned-off)