# Remove SIRI suggestion from lock screen

Tags: ios, ipad, siri

My lock-screen has a SIRI suggestion to play a podcast.  I turned off Settings/Siri & Search/Suggestions in Lock Screen, but that didn't get rid of it.

How do I remove it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Also a power cycle might make it clear if the notification is stale / from before you made the change or you're still seeing a suggested app based on location.

Comment: What happens if you swipe it from left to right to clear it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Siri suggestion still showing after turned off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252925/siri-suggestion-still-showing-after-turned-off)